# Remote SSH from local machine : Connection refused

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I'm running Vagrant VM on the left window. I created a user name 'student' in my VM but when I try to ssh my user 'student' from my local machine terminal, it gives me error

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, which points to your local machine but not the virtual machine.

You should use address `10.0.2.15` listed by `ifconfig` from your virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I figure out that my firewall block port 22 that's why the problem persists. Now it's resolved.

Comment: This problem is solved on Linux. But still, on window problems persist. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/vbqrqvl